# OnClick to TextView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

How to set text in the Text View by using button on click both are present in the same Activity?

> I have already used the Text View on using the same Text View the Stopped working

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Comment: Post your codes as well as stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Use the setter *setText()* in the button's on click listener.

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)     {

        myTextView.setText("new text");

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that can help you with this.

```
Button button;
TextView textView;

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text);
// set the text view inside the button's OnClickListener() method

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v){
      textView.setText("Hello World");
   }
});
```